# Composer error while installing Laravel: 'mbstring' is missing?

Tags: laravel, frameworks, composer-php

I've decided to try out Laravel and I've been going on and off with the installation because of how tedious it is in comparison to OOP PHP.

Nontheless I'm trying to execute the 'composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist' command on my cmd(.~/wamp/www/) and it created the Laravel folder but gives me this output:

```
*Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.1.4)
    Loading from cache

Created project in C:\wamp\www\laravel
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.1.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.1.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte
nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel
/framework[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.
8].
C:\wamp\www>*
```

I am using windows.

I have tried installing a fresh composer, I have tried copying a laravel directory and placing it in my /www manually.

I've made sure that WAMP is using all modules and extensions according to what I read.

I've edited the php.ini file and taken of the semi-colons where necessary.

And now after a bit of Google Searching,  I am lost.

Could anybody help me with this problem please, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

**Below is my PHP.ini file**

So I couldn't paste the whole thing, but take a look at it here:

http://jpst.it/AAhW

Comment: Is there a line in php.ini with "mbstring" in it? Is it commented out? Have you restarted WAMP afterwards?

Comment: There are loads. Some of which are commented out, like:
';mbstring.http_input=UTF-8', however, the:
'extension=php_mbstring.dll' is not commmented out anymore.

Yes I have restarted WAMP several times.

Comment: And does the php_mbstring.dll file exist with the other extensions?

Comment: Yes it is , im confused.

Comment: I am not sure with wamp, but sometimes there is a separate php.ini for command line programs than for the web server.

Comment: Can you copy paste your php.ini file?

Comment: there should be two `php.ini` files in wamp `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\php.ini` for cli and `\wamp\bin\php\{phpversion}\phpForApache.ini` for running php in apache. make sure you edit the correct one

Comment: @RomainLanz Pasted it.

Comment: Search for `extension_dir` and remove it (with the lowercase "c") and then uncomment the other (with the uppercase "c").

Comment: @RomainLanz Did so, and I've replaced the link with the new php ini file. However, it's still giving the same error. I'm starting to think something else is the problem, like the directories, the composer installation or the laravel version or something. Because it's usually not this tricky. But I've re-installed everything so I'm not sure. Is it looking for a different php/ directory completely different from the WAMP one? I don't know. I'm definitely going to learn from this once I get it fixed though.

Comment: make sure you edit the correct `php.ini`: Run `php -r "phpinfo();" > phpinfo.txt` in command line, open the generated `phpinfo.txt` and search for  `Loaded Configuration File`. You can also search for `mbstring` in this text file to see if the extension was loaded. There should also be a `php_error_log` file within your `php` directory (or `php\logs` sub directord) see if you can find errors regarding `extension_dir` or `mbstring`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed assistance. I did what you said, the mbstring is: Multibyte Support => enabled according to the file, and the loaded config seems to be correct. I'll check the logs.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here's the solution.

1. Go to your php.ini file.
2. Locate the extension "extension=php_mbstring.dll". (ctrl+f might not work, just locate the long list with extensions in php.ini)
3. Uncomment the extension, you do this by removing the semicolon in the same line.
4. Save your php.ini file.

This probably won't be the last time you'll encounter something like this. As a rule of thumb, read the error carefully and make the appropriate change to your php.ini file.

Good luck!

Comment: On AWS AMI linux if you are running php56 you will need to add. extension=php56_mbstring.dll instead.  Anytime you change your php.ini file you should also restart your http server.  On my system: sudo service httpd restart

Comment: @NateBunney - will you help for this question ? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50423893/2034750

Answer (score 10):

Installing `php-mbstring` using,

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

should fix this.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of errors when i was trying to install on my linux machine :

1. laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
2. phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

> sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
>
> sudo apt-get install php-dom

So in short all the error such such as

- jenssegers/mongodb v3.2.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].

  - jenssegers/mongodb v3.2.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
  - jenssegers/mongodb v3.2.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
  - mongodb/mongodb 1.1.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.2.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.

you can simply run the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install php-*

Thanks