# Unable to install laravel 5 on windows via composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get started with laravel on windows and here is the command I tried:

`rahul@rahulserver MINGW64 /d/PhpIdeaProjects/LaravelLearning
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel learning-laravel-5`

Here is the output I get:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.22)
    Loading from cache

Created project in learning-laravel-5
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for danielstjules/stringy 1.9.0 -> satisfiable by danielstjules/stringy[1.9.0].
    - danielstjules/stringy 1.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

So how shall I move on and have it working?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690561/composer-error-while-installing-laravel-mbstring-is-missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requested dependencies require the php extension `mbstring` as the error explains.

> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system

So install the extension and it should install flawless.

`mbstring` is built in the `libapache2-mod-php5` package. Run

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

---

For windows environments check your `php.ini` and uncomment the line `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` to `extension=php_mbstring.dll` - then restart your webserver.