# Composer install with laravel quickstart not working

Tags: laravel, composer-php

At the moment I am following the [basic Laravel tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart).
I cloned the folder and ran composer install. Which lead to the following error : http://pastebin.com/FijE9SN5.

This is what the composer.json looks like:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

So I searched on google for errors. I came to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690561/composer-error-while-installing-laravel-mbstring-is-missing#answer-33736248) on stackoverflow saying I needed to delete the semicolon in front of ext-mbstring in my php ini file. But it's still not working. I am clueless right now. Anyone knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment due to my reputation, however the first thing you should do is to is to follow the instructions in the error. By that, you should check whether ext-mbstring and ext-dom are enabled in your php.ini. You say that you've deleted the semicolon in front of ext-mbstring, but have you also done so for the dom extension as well?

Also, verify that php-xml is installed as shown [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-do-i-install-the-dom-extension-for-php7):

`sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it, turns out I had to run

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

just like ThePurpleK said.
And I had to run

```
apt-get install php-mbstring.
```

Thanks anyways!