# XAMPP : composer returns error instead create new laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, ubuntu-16.04

Using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Installed PHP in two places with different version, in root 7.0 and XAMPP 5.6 , the composer installed globally, now I am not able to create project by composer from lamp/htdocs.

- xampp running fine.
- composer installed and running fine.

Error :

```
Notebook-PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30): Loading from cache
Created project in blog
> php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.36 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.35 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.34 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.33 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.32 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Checked by enable and disable php_mbstring.dll from root php.ini but getting same error. how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: @parthu_panther - getting error `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/username
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section`

Comment: what is the command that you used to create new project when this error striked?

Comment: @parthu_panther - `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"`

Comment: after changine php.ini dont forget to restart

Comment: may be some packages are missing. try to reinstall xampp from verified source and try again.

Comment: you can resolve this issue by installing mbstring extension

Comment: @arun - restarted but same issue. will reinstall now.

Comment: @parthu_panther - Yes going to reinstall now, but have one doubts ubuntu already have installed php 7.0, Will it case any issue for XAMPP 5.6 with php 5.6. ? will composer give any Issue ?

Comment: I would prefer the latest xamp version with php 7.2+. it improves performance. mbstring will be by default installed with that. Also the laravel version 5.4 requires php>=5.6.4 which is not satisfied with your current 5.6 version. So latest version of xampp with php 7.2+ would be fine for both the packages, dependencies and not to forget it will simultaneously increase your performance.

Comment: @parthu_panther - Its most usefull command, and I started using `sudo apt lamp-server^`, it checks ubuntu php versions and installs all requires packages. and stores in /var/www/html. I am fine with this. using php 7.0.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled XAMP and Installed LAMP in different way, but got the same issue :

`sudo apt install lamp-server^`

then solved by enable php mods :

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Followed : https://askubuntu.com/a/767970/509965